# Produce context managed EntityManager programmatically

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager, jta

I'm working on a JavaEE application which uses JPA and is deployed on JBoss/Wildfly. I have my `persistence.xml` and `standalone.xml` properly configured for JPA to recognize the datasource. I understand that the normal way to obtain a context managed EntityManager is the following:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "foo")
EntityManager em;
```

However, in my usecase the application defining the datasource and the library accessing it using JPA are separate. I need a way to programmatically produce an `EntityManager` by its persistence unit name. I understand that the easiest way to do this is this:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("foo").createEntityManager()
```

However, this gives me an *application managed* entity manager, which forces me to handle transactions myself. I want to get a *context managed* entity manager, where I demarcate transactions by CDI-injecting `UserTransaction` or in similar ways.
Is there a way to create an `EntityManager` at runtime and attach its transaction to the current context?

The original code worked around this by providing one global, application-scoped entitymanager. This way every occurance of `EntityManager` obviously has the same transaction. Besides other problems, this causes errors when trying to parallelize queries, as `EntityManager` is not thread safe. That's why I am currently trying to create entity manager instances ad-hoc, but keep the transaction semantics.

Comment: Could you please describe the use case in a little more detail? Why can't you simply configure the library with an injected `EntityManager`, in the bean that uses the library? If the library is CDI-enabled, why not use a `@Produces` method with a custom qualifier that the library will require? Finally, why not use `@PersistenceContext` without `unitName`?

Comment: Using that generation of an EntityManager will create a new EntityManagerFactory for each EntityManager you need! and not close them either!!!

Comment: @crizzis The application using the library supposedly doesn't know about JPA, only about some persistence unit name, which happens to be implemented with JPA in one case. I need to supply a unitName, because I need to support multiple concurrent datasource. This is also why can't just statically list all datasources as producers: it's dynamic. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

A Wildfly-specific solution is detailed here: 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-BindingEntityManagerFactory%2FEntityManagertoJNDI. After following the steps described in the link, you should be able to obtain the reference to the `EntityManager` via JNDI (`NamingContext.lookup()`).

I still have the distinct feeling that you have an XY problem. Your comment adds to the confusion, as the statements 'I'm working on a JavaEE application which uses JPA' and 'The application using the library supposedly doesn't know about JPA' are mutually exclusive. Also, a 'persistence unit name, which happens to be implemented with JPA in one case' is misleading because a persistence unit is a concept specific to JPA.

I fail to understand why you 'can't just statically list all datasources as producers' but 'one global, application-scoped entitymanager' works fine as a workaround. Are persistence units not statically listed in `persistence.xml`? I hope the above link works for you, but if you add an example use case to your question, I can try to suggest a better solution if you like.